# set dropdown with inputbox using internet controls

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer-11

I already tried too many topics before, so I decided to post it.
I'm trying to select a field in a list box with the follow html code:

```html
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="Filter_Grupo1">Reporte por</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm chosen" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Reporte por must be a number." data-val-required="El campo Reporte por es obligatorio." id="Filter_Grupo1" name="Filter.Grupo1"><option selected="selected" value="1">Marca</option>
<option value="2">Modelo</option>
<option value="3">SubModelo</option>
<option value="4">Versi&#243;n</option>
<option value="5">Combustible</option>
<option value="6">Motor</option>
<option value="7">Transmision</option>
<option value="8">Segmento</option>
<option value="9">SubSegmento</option>
<option value="10">Tipo</option>
<option value="11">Origen</option>
<option value="12">Tipo Comprador</option>
<option value="13">Provincia</option>
<option value="14">Region</option>
<option value="15">Pa&#237;s Origen</option>
<option value="16">Localidad</option>
</select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

To make this selection, I tried:

```
    Set oSelect = oHTMLDoc.getElementById("Filter_Grupo1")
    oSelect.Focus
    oSelect.SelectedIndex = 6
    oSelect.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

As result the option will be highlighted[image]

But when this dropdown is closed it still remains in the same way:[image]

I already tried to use the Twebst library, the result was the same.
Glad for any help!

Comment: does the HTML actually indicate there is an OnChange event?

Comment: I got what you said, I guess. Doesn't have anyone among the html. I imagined that it works in a different way.  "oSelect.FireEvent ("onchange")"  is making nothing. So what do you suggest?